# OSX Scripting Bridge Options for Photoshop

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, photoshop, scripting-bridge

I am trying to save image from **Adobe Photoshop** as `PNG`, I have achieved this with the following code.

```
AdobePhotoshopApplication* psApp = [SBApplication applicationWithBundleIdentifier:@"com.adobe.Photoshop"];
AdobePhotoshopDocument *curDoc   = [psApp currentDocument];
AdobePhotoshopDocument *temp     = [curDoc saveIn:[NSURL URLWithString:[path stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]] as:AdobePhotoshopSvFmPNG copying:YES appending:AdobePhotoshopE300LowercaseExtension withOptions:nil];
```

Well the only problem here is that even a simple image takes 4-5 MB. Now i want to provide `AdobePhotoshopSaveOptions` in `saveIn:as:copying:appending:withOptions:`

I can provide compression value in options, as it can be seen in

```
// Settings related to saving a PNG document
@interface AdobePhotoshopPNGSaveOptions : AdobePhotoshopSaveOptions    
@property NSInteger compression;  // compression used on the image. ( 0 - 9; default: 0 )
@property BOOL interlaced;  // should rows be interlaced? ( default: false )    
@end
```

Problem is, when i create options and pass it to `saveIn` method i get the following error

```
*** NSForwarding: warning: object 0x618000030280 of class '__NSMessageBuilder' does not implement doesNotRecognizeSelector: -- abort
```

I created the `AdobePhotoshopPNGSaveOptions` as

```
AdobePhotoshopPNGSaveOptions *options = [[psApp classForScriptingClass:@"PNG save options"] new];
```

I have no idea where to go from here.